# Javascript Image toggle/switcher triggered with a button: How can I get the button text to change

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, button

So I have been in the process of having an image switcher to toggle images. What I am doing is having 2 images of the same size that are displaying a clean and labeled version. Simple right? Here is what I have so far:

```
<button id="button-switch"> Hide/Show Redlines</button><script>(function() 
{'use strict';function init(){var el=document.getElementById('deconstructed');
document.getElementById('button-switch').onclick=function(){el.id=='deconstructed'?(el.id='t-b',el.

    // PLACE CLEAN IMAGE HERE //////////////
    src='_images/clean_image.png',el.alt='my t-b'):(el.id='deconstructed',el.

    // PLACE *LABELED* IMAGE HERE //////////////
    src='_images/labeled_image.png',el.alt='my deconstructed');}}window.addEventListener('load',init,false);})();</script>

    <!-- PLACE *LABELED* ONE MORE TIME HERE    
                                                            --> <div><img id="deconstructed" 
    src="_images/labeled_image.png" 
                                                                    alt="my deconstructed"></div>
```

In this code, the text on the button is the same. I by no means are decent at Javascript and I am amazed I was able to get this series of things to cooperate. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Hi firstly write clean code so that everyone understands.

```
<input type='button'
       id="button-switch"
       value='Hide/Show Redlines' / >

<script>(function () {
    'use strict';
    function init() {

        var el = document.getElementById('deconstructed');
        var button = document.getElementById('button-switch');
        button.onclick = function () {
            el.id == 'deconstructed' ? (el.id = 't-b', el.src = '_images/clean_image.png', el.alt = 'my t-b',
                        button.value = 't-b'
                )


                : (el.id = 'deconstructed', el.src = '_images/labeled_image.png', el.alt = 'my deconstructed',
                    button.value = ' Hide/Show Redlines');
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
})();
</script>

< !--PLACE * LABELED * ONE   MORE   TIME   HERE    -- >

< div > < img id = "deconstructed" src = "_images/labeled_image.png" alt = "my deconstructed" > < / div >
```

hope this helps...